# Print report template after replacing placeholders

Tags: c#, .net, openxml

I have to print a report in my application whose template already my application will have in separate word file.
My application will replace some placeholder in template and then print the report.

I have found below URL useful and related to my task.
http://www.jarredcapellman.com/2012/10/22/c-openxml-mail-merge-complete-example/

So, do i really need to use above approach or there can be some easier way too.
Because my client don't want to use libraries and the above one is using OpenXMLSDK 2.0 library

Please suggest the best way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I used the OpenXMLSDK and you can simply add the DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll to your bin directory and don't need to install anything extra.

Other than that I'd know of 2 more possibilities to achieve it without OpenXML:

1. you could use Word Interop - you don't really want to do it
2. .docx is simply few compressed xml files, so you could unzip it and handle the files directly. You need to get to know the tags and files a bit, but if the keywords are easy to detect you could also just try it with a find/replace which would be much easier